# How did wið shift to denote association rather than opposition?

Tags: etymology, old-english

Millar doesn't expound the semantic shift at all, but Wiktionary tries to. But wið is a functional morpheme, that at large change with less probability. So why did it shift "to denote association rather than opposition, from senses of attaining proximity through movement towards and then rest at a thing, displacing Middle English mid (“with”), from Old English mid (“with”)"?

> A few words are easy, especially the little grammatical ones: *her* is ‘here’, and *is* ‘and’,
> *æfter* is ‘after’, *þær* is ‘there’, *his* is ‘his’, *þæt* is ‘that’, and *him* is ‘him’ – at least sometimes!
> Only slightly harder are cyning and its contracted form *cyng* ‘king’, rad ‘rode’, niht
> ‘nights’ and wolde, woldon ‘would’. And you have probably spotted that sæt is just our
> word ‘sat’. Barely recognizable is aðas ‘oaths’, but, if you ignore the prefix *ge-*, you can
> see that *gefeaht* is the same word as our ‘fought’. You may be startled to learn that the
> mysterious-looking *ealne* is just our word ‘all’ with a grammatical ending attached. Finally,
> that word *wið* is just our word ‘with’, but note that the word meant ‘against’ in Old English.
> The Old English word for ‘with’ was *mid*, which has completely disappeared except in the
> compound ‘midwife’ (literally, ‘with-woman’); its job has been taken over by *wið*, which
> in turn has handed over its original meaning to yet another word, *against*, except in the
> ambiguous phrase *he fought with his brother* and in the verb *withstand*, which has a similar
> meaning to ‘stand against’.

Revised by Robert McColl Millar, *Trask's Historical Linguistics* [(2015 3e)](https://www.routledge.com/Trasks-Historical-Linguistics/Millar-Trask/p/book/9780415706582), p 3. [Trask died in 2004.](https://www.theguardian.com/news/2004/apr/08/guardianobituaries1)

> The items
> in the list are all (supposedly) of the sort I called *basic vocabulary* in Chapter 2. That is,
> they are words that change more slowly than vocabulary in general: pronouns, low numerals,
> body-part names, simple verbs and adjectives, and so on, although it is important to note that, as Dixon (1997), among others, points out, and we have already discussed in
> Chapter 2, some cultures may alter ‘central’ items of vocabulary regularly, in order to avoid
> taboo words and names.

*Op. cit.* p 352.

> ### Etymology 1
>
> From [Middle English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_English) *[with](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/with#Middle_English)*, from [Old English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English) *[wiþ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wi%C3%BE#Old_English)* (“against, opposite, toward, with”), from [Proto-Germanic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Germanic_language) *[*wiþi](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/wi%C3%BEi&action=edit&redlink=1)*, a shortened form of [Proto-Germanic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Germanic_language) *[*wiþrą](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/wi%C3%BEr%C4%85)* (“against”), which see for its derivation and other descendants cognate to the English preposition. In Middle English, the word shifted to denote association rather than opposition, from senses of attaining proximity through movement towards and then rest at a thing, displacing [Middle English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_English) *[mid](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mid#Middle_English)* (“with”), from [Old English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English) *[mid](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mid#Old_English)* (“with”), from [Proto-Germanic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Germanic_language) *[*midi](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/midi)*; an earlier model of this meaning shift exists in cognate [Old Norse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Norse) *[við](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vi%C3%B0#Old_Norse)*; elsewhere, the converse meaning shift is exposed by [Old South Arabian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_South_Arabian) __‎ (byn, “between, amid”) spawning [Old South Arabian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_South_Arabian) __‎ (bn, “against”) and even likewise frequent reverse meaning __‎ (bn, “from”).

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/with#Etymology_1

Comment: It didn't really shift meanings (not as dramatically as your quote makes it seem, at least), OE *wiþ* already meant 'with'. It's just that like *against*, which can mean 'up against' (e.g. leaning against a wall) in addition to 'opposite' (fighting against something), it had a superficially contradictory secondary meaning, which it just dropped.

Comment: On what do you base the fact that _wiþ_ is a functional morpheme and thus less likely to undergo semantic shift? Prepositions are amongst the vocabulary **most** likely to shift their semantics because they describe spatial relations, and those are always slippy and hard to pinpoint. It’s extremely common – the rule, even – to find cognate prepositions in related languages with totally different meanings. @Cairnarvon OE _wiþ_ may have meant ‘against’, but PG _wiþra_ doesn’t seem to have. So yes, it did change as much as the quotes indicate, just earlier than the question (seemingly) assumes.